# Display custom fields in assignment block (SAP CRM 7.0)

Tags: sap-crm

I tried to post this on the SDN forums (SAP forums) with very very very little help...seems like anytime I post an SAP topic no one can help :(.  So I decided to post on Stack Overflow and can only hope there must be some SAP CRM gurus on here...

Here was the original link I posted on the SAP Forums, so maybe the little help I did get on the SAP forums someone can follow along by clicking the link: https://answers.sap.com/questions/7772631/add-custom-fields-to-assignment-block.html.

Here is the description:

> We are running SAP CRM 7.0. We are using the opportunity module as well as "Create Follow Up" (Sales Order / Quotation) so that you have a one to many relationship (1 opportunity may contain many sales orders). I have 2 custom fields inside the Sales Cycle (Quotation) module "Actual Sales Order Value" and "Current Points".
>
> What I am trying to do is take these 2 custom fields and add them to the assignment block called "Linked Transactions" in the Opportunities module. But when I look at all the available fields for this assignment block these 2 custom fields are nt available.
>
> I do not see any way of adding these 2 fields to this assignment block. The only thing I see is "Create New Field". But I do not want to create a new field I just want to reference 2 fields from the Sales Cycle module inside of this assignment block.
>
> Does anyone know if it is possible to add 2 custom created fields that are in the Sales cycle module to add them to the opportunities assignment block that is called linked transactions ?

Thanks,
Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got this.  I had to use the GENIL_MODEL_BROWSER to see the relationships between these components.  The assignment block was the component BTDOCFLOW so I had to enhance this and the view and the context node.
Then in the folder attributes for this context node i had to add a new attribute (right click add).  I used the GENIL_MODEL_BROWSER to start at the BTOrder relationship to get to BTOrderHeader to finally get to BTAdminH.  I then referenced these fields and generated getter / setter methods.  In the get method I had to change my code a bit to start at BTOrder component.

Reference this link for more information: http://forums.sdn.sap.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1875030&tstart=0